# binded value for a control outside a repeater

Tags: c#, asprepeater

Just for curiosity can i give a control that is outside a repeater a binneded value

for example :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="topicRepeater" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<table border="0" id="bodyTable" runat="server" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-top: 6px; padding-right: 30px; padding-left: 5px; width: 50px;">
<img src='App_Themes/WebPortalTheme/images/ProfilePicSmall/<%# Eval("ProPic") %>'
 style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" />
<div runat="server" id="username" style="padding-left: 8px; color: #002D79;">
<%# Eval("UserName") %></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
 <telerik:RadTextBox ID="EditedReplyTxt" Text='<%# Eval("msg_text")%>' runat="server"  Width="300px" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="100px"></telerik:RadTextBox>
```

Comment: Why dont you use it in repeater

Comment: bcs i want 2 access it from client side in my scenario and dealing with repeater items from client side is hard

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, read this example

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/4hx47hfe(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: didn't work for me it gives me this error :Error 52 'System.Web.UI.Control' does not contain a definition for 'DataItem' and no extension method 'DataItem' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: add reference to System.Web and add   using System.Web.UI;